# How to extract component from the Package (un-managed)

Tags: salesforcedx, unmanaged-package

I'm trying to pull the components (fields/objects....) from the un-managed package but I could not find any way using APIs or APEX is that even possible ?

Here is the example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sfdx force:source:retrieve has a "package name" option:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "My Package Name"
```

You can also retrieve a package using the MDAPI by specifying a package name (e.g. via the Ant Migration Tool, Workbench, etc). DX has an MDAPI option, too:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -p "My Package Name"
```

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox, is that possible using rest apis ?

Comment: @NickKahn I've never seen one, you'd have to look through the docs. What's your actual objective? It feels like you may have actually asked an [X-Y](http://xyproblem.info/) question.

Comment: my actual objective is to find out what components in that package using apis :)

Comment: @NickKahn As long as you're not trying to do it in Apex, SFDX is probably the easiest solution at the moment.